# How to parse and interpret "никому прохода не даст”?

Tags: значения, идиомы

> (From young to old) – **никому прохода не даст**!

They are talking about a ladykiller's taste in women covering a broad spectrum from young to old.

I wonder if this phrase means something along the lines of "no one slips under his radar"?

Comment: it's borderline being a stalker, won't let anyone pass by/through, like blocking their way

Comment: @БаянКупи-ка Hi. So the literal meaning is something like "he won't give/allow a passage to anyone (so that he could chat them up)"?

Comment: hi, yes, that's right

Comment: the purposes for which one won't give passage may be various, not only romantic advances, and these are derived from the context

Answer (score 2):

"Не давать прохода" literally means that wherever you go, there's a crowd gathering around you, so you can't go through. Because you are so popular, etc. It's usually exaggerated, for example, if you're a pretty girl every man is trying to hit on, people may say: "Ей мужики не дают прохода." - although, literally, that's not true, you could just ignore them and go where you need. I don't remember seeing it used the other way around (e. g. a single person "не даёт прохода" to multiple other persons), but I guess that's a legitimate usage as well.

Comment: You are correct, usage of the phrase for a single person is rather unusual. [Rus Corpora has only 6 examples](http://search1.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%EF%F0%EE%F5%EE%E4%E0+%ED%E5+%E4%E0%E5%F2)

Comment: i'm familiar with the use for a single person

Comment: Hmm, never seen "Не давать прохода" in the sense of being popular, seen only in a sense of being combative or annoying.

Answer (score 2):

Your translation *"no one slips under his radar"* is very close, if you assume that *"no one"* are all women.

> Никому прохода не даст / никому прохода не даёт - *He keeps bugging / harassing everyone (implied every girl)*

Another idiom with a similar meaning:

> Ни одной юбки не пропустит - *He won't miss a single skirt.*

Comment: Hi. This sort of rather *unique/special* idiom -- where can you look them up?

Comment: @Con-gras-tue-les-chiens I can't find a dictionary that has idioms discussed in this post. In general, there are phraseological dictionaries, such as  [by Larionova](https://www.litres.ru/u-a-larionova/frazeologicheskiy-slovar-sovremennogo-russkogo-yazyka/) and [by Fyodorov](http://rus-yaz.niv.ru/doc/phraseological-literary-dictionary/index.htm). But they are intended for native speakers and are difficult to use for learners of Russian.